# Nodejs find and return specific element?

Tags: node.js, express

This is reading config file and return bunch of array i wanna return specific element like details, currently its return complete array i want simple  details element.

```
const lay = {
    key: null,
    information: {
        time: false,
        rate: false

    },
    details: {
        tip: false,
        edit: true

    }
};
```

i am using

```
transform() {
     return   conf.find((d) => {
            return d;
   });
}
```

Comment: The `lay` property is not an array. It's and object. Can you clarify your question? Otherwise `find` method will work for you. But you have to run it on an array.

Comment: actully i need only return this area

details: {
        tip: false,
        edit: true

    }

Details object

Comment: like `let myDetails = lay.details`?

Comment: What is your input? Is `lay` object or array of `lay` objects? Than what do you need to return? Just `lay.details` or `lay.details` of specific element in array?

Answer (score 0):

```
const lay = {
  key: null,
  information: {
    time: false,
    rate: false
  },
  details: {
    tip: false,
    edit: true
  }
};

let transform = () => lay.details;

transform();
```

Comment: its showing in consol but not returning this element.

Comment: @adnankhan where do you want it to be return?

Comment: I am doing this but not work
    transform() {
         return   dspConfig.find((d) => {
                return d['info'];
       });
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
const lay = {
    key: null,
    information: {
        time: false,
        rate: false

    },
    details: {
        tip: false,
        edit: true

    }
};

function transform() {
     return  lay.details; //or lay['details']
}
```